# Magento 2 : How to Remove Customer Account Navigation Link Without XML

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account, navigation

[image]

I want to remove customer account navigation tab without use of xml file.

How to remove this ABC customer account navigation link in magento2?

Please help me...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The only other way to remove it without using layout xml is to create a custom module. eg https://github.com/magepal/magento2-customeraccountlinksmanager

Answer (score 3):

In Magento 2 these links are controlled by the class `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation`. This block is added to the sidebar in the xml `Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`.

To add a new link you need to reference this block and then can add a child block as follows.

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active" name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Wish List</argument>
            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

If the link you are trying to remove is built like the wishlist you can turn it on or off via the system configuration (see `ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"`).

If the link you are trying to remove is not built with such a flag then you will have to remove the block via it's name as follows:

```
<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: I want to check that if value is true then remove this link when this dashboard page load.. If value is false then this link not removed. How is it possible?